# How to add multiple classNames in to fullcalendar event object and deleting with one specified class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

Does anyone know how I can add multiple class names in to one event?

Currently my event object looks something like this.

```
  var eventObject = {
            title: displayText,
            start: item.startDate,
            end : item.endDate,
            allDay:true,
            color: '#BABBBF',
            editable : false,
            className : "user_block"
    }
```

When I tried something like this

```
var eventObject = {
                title: displayText,
                start: item.startDate,
                end : item.endDate,
                allDay:true,
                color: '#BABBBF',
                editable : false,
                className : "user_block bday_block"
        };
```

The following code doesn't seem to excute with normal behaviour where it is suppose to remove all events with the "user_block" class

```
$("#calendar").fullCalendar('removeEvents', function(event) {
    return event.className == "user_block";
});
```

Any ideas on how to solve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/):

> **ClassName**: String/Array. Optional. A CSS class (or array of classes)
>   that will be attached to this event's element.

Therefore you should use an array of strings to attach multiple classes to the event.

This should solve your problem:

```
var eventObject = {
        title: displayText,
        start: item.startDate,
        end : item.endDate,
        allDay: true,
        color: '#BABBBF',
        editable : false,
        className : ["user_block", "bday_block"]
}
```